# What is the real usage of apc_cas() function?

Tags: php, apc

I wonder what a real life example that I need to use the [`apc_cas`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-cas.php) function in PHP.

Comment: This change the cache variable with a new one but I also saw in the comments for apc_store: Note APC version 3.1.3 there is a bug (http://pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=16814) that will display a cache slam averted warning for all writes to a cache var that exists.
I am guessing that using this function will not generate that warning

Comment: Hope link will help you: http://www.cnblogs.com/argb/p/3604344.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple example is a counter. Assume we have a key `counter` and a function which increases the counter (note that this would be better suited for the `apc_inc` function but let's play along):

```
function incCounter(){
    //Get the current value increment and set
    $c = apc_fetch('counter');
    $c++;
    apc_store('counter',$c);
}
```

However the above has an issue. If two requests occur at the same time both will get the same value of `$c` and increment it meaning the counter will only be incremented by one.

Using `apc_cas` however let's you guarantee that the value you are updating is the old one and that it hasn't been changed in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Assures you that no one else updated the value in that key. Is for that reason that you have to pass the $old value. If the current value is different to your knowlegment of the key value (in this case $old) the key will not be updated and false is returned.

Implementation of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap commonly used in key stores databases.